# Setting up functional tests with custom database data in Symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony, testing, phpunit

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have this schema.

A `Machine`, `Site` and `User` is associated with a `Task`. A `Task` can have many (say at least twenty) different `TaskDetail`'s.

```
Task

task_id (int PK)
machine_id (int FK)
user_id (int FK)
site_id (int FK)
task_name (varchar)
task_time (int)

TaskDetail

task_detail_id (int PK)
task_id (int FK)
task_detail_value (varchar)

Machine

machine_id (int PK)
machine_name (varchar)

User

user_id (int PK)
user_name (varchar)
user_register_time (int)

Site

site_id (int PK)
site_name (varchar)
```

How can I best populate test data with Symfony? I am using PHPUnit as the testing framework.

I have written functional tests in Symfony before, but never to test data from the database. It's always been limited to simpler tests (does the dropdown menu have the following items in it, etc).

So for example, on my list of tasks page - I wanted to test that 5 tasks appear. How would I set up a test such that I'd populate the database with 5 tasks (that I imagine I will need to hard code somewhere?), then test that the output of that page shows those 5 tasks I created?

I've looked at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html and a few other pages and I've yet to find anything which outlines how to do what I am asking - and it seems like a fairly simple test case to me.

So any pointers are certainly welcome. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.elao.com/fr/blog/symfony2-how-to-share-objects-when-writing-fixtures) article

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Doctrine Fixtures, they allow you to load controlled data sets into your database for testing or even to make sure you have some initial data.

symfony2 has very good integration with doctrine fixtures through [DoctrineFixturesBundle.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

Write fixtures for all the entities that are needed to make sure there is enough data for tests .  Then you can actually load the fixtures using the console command the bundle offers. Then you can do your functional testing as usual.

Also follow these articles to unit test the Code which interacts with database.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/database.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html

Comment: Fixtures really are the way to go. In addition to this, you can use [LiipFunctionnalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle) which integrates them better in tests and uses a Sqlite3 DB for tests.

Comment: Thanks - that bundle looks great.